# .NET Core 2 IdentityServer 4 Cors only working on localhost

Tags: c#, .net-core

As the title suggests, I am receiving Cors errors when I deploy my API to my server (IIS 7.5).

I have a slightly modified version of the IdentityServer 4 sample for Implicit flow authentication - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication/src

Everything works as expected running locally; I receive an access token, and I am able to call a secured API endpoint. However, when I deploy the API to my IIS 7.5 server (but not the Identity Server or the JS Client) I am receiving the typical CORS origin issues.

The general setup is

**IdentitServer:** http://localhost:5001

**JS Client:**     http://localhost:5003/

**API:**           http://api.on.the.internet (or http://localhost:5001 locally)

My startup is barely modified beyond the initial sample:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = MyHelper.AuthorityUrl; // identity server url
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "api1";
            });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("default",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        });

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors("default");
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

And my controller -

```
[EnableCors("default")]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Authorize]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        etc...
    }
}
```

I've searched pretty exhaustively, and it doesn't seem like anyone else has posted this issue. So I thought I'd reach out and see if anyone had any high level advice or solution to this issue. Anyone else run up against this issue?

Many thanks!

-Marc

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your pre-flight requests contain the appropriate Access-Control headers. For example:

```
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,cache-control,content-type,pragma
```

Pay special attention to `Access-Control-Request-Headers`. You can check this quickly on chrome dev-tools network tab and selecting the failing request.

[image]

Comment: Thank you fernandoespinosa.The issue was related to the inability of the authentication middleware to reach the authority. Woops! Trivial and easy fix. Will post a quick answer.